# Suduko when click ask for a number and print

Tags: python

```
from processing import *
turn = None
player_letter = None
computer_letter = None
board = [ [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None], 
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],  
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None],]

x = input("What number would you want")





def drawBoard(board):
  for y in range(len(board)):
    for x in range(len(board[0])):
      strokeWeight(5,0,0,0)
      noFill()
      rect(0,0,150,150)
      rect(150,0,150,150)
      rect(300,0,150,150)
      rect(0,150,150,150)
      rect(0,300,150,150)
      rect(150,150,150,150)
      rect(150,300,150,150)
      rect(300,150,150,150)
      rect(300,300,150,150)
      stroke(0,0,0)
      strokeWeight(1,0,0,0)
      rect(x*50, y*50, 50, 50)




def drawLetters(board):
  for row in range(len(board)):
    for col in range(len(board[0])):
      if board[row][col] != None:
        textSize(32)
        fill(0,0,0)
        text(board[row][col], col*50+12.5, 
        row*50+37.5)


def get_starting_player():
  random_num = int(random(2))
  return 'player'


def run_player_turn(player_letter):
  global board
  if mouse.pressed and board[mouse.y//50][mouse.x//50] == None and (mouse.x< 450) and (mouse.y<450):
    board[mouse.y//50][mouse.x//50] = player_letter
    x = input("What number would you want")
    return True
  else:
    return False


def setup():
  size(450, 450)
  global board
  global turn
  drawBoard(board)
  turn = get_starting_player()
  global player_letter
  global computer_letter

  if turn == 'player':
    player_letter = x
    computer_letter = '2'
  else:
    player_letter = x
    computer_letter = '2'

def check_win(board, letter):
  return False


def check_tie(board):
  for row in range(len(board)):
    for col in range(len(board[0])):
      if board[row][col] == None:
        return False
  return True



game_ended = False
def draw():
  global board
  global player_letter
  global computer_letter
  global turn
  global game_ended
  if turn == 'player' and game_ended == False:
    if run_player_turn(player_letter): 
      if check_win(board, player_letter):
        game_ended = True
      elif check_tie(board):
        game_ended = True
        print("ya tied person so sad")
      else:
        turn = 'player'

  drawLetters(board)


run()
```

Right now I want to make a replication of the game suduko in python 3, I need help on when click a box on the board ask for number and then you can change the box to the desired number, I have `x = input("What number would you want")` which I want to activate and change the empty box to the desired number. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, be a bit more specific in your technical question.

Comment: I want to make it so that when I click on a box i can input a number and it would change the variable X to it, then every time I click another box it repeates the process

Comment: My advise to you is to do not post your whole program as a question. Just the part you need help. We cannot solve your general problem, but we would be glad to help you with every part of the main problem that you need. So far, I can only see a big code and a not so well formatted question. That's why I commented.